# How to draw graph with logarithmic scale by getting input from AJAX call in canvasjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var dataPoints = [];
  // fetching the json data from api via AJAX call.
  var X = [];
  var Y = [];
  var data = [];

  function loadJSON(callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', ' https://api.myjson.com/bins/cixax', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
        callback(xobj.responseText);
      }
    }
    xobj.send(null);
  }
  loadJSON(function(response) {
    var response;
    var field = JSON.parse(response);
    var values = [];
    //Iterating and storing leads & visits in a variable.
    var $this = field;
    for (var key in $this) {
      if ($this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var data = $this[key].dates;
        for (var val in data) {
          values.push({
            "X": data[val].visits,
            "Y": data[val].leads
          });
        }
      }
    }
    dataPoints = ({
      "values": values
    });
  });

  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    title: {
      text: "Log Scale on Axis Y - Workaround using Linear Axis"
    },
    axisY: {
      //valueFormatString: "0.## E0",
      title: "In log scale",
      labelFormatter: function(e) {
        var lable = Math.pow(10, e.value);
        if (lable >= 1000)
          lable = CanvasJS.formatNumber(lable / 1000) + "k";
        else
          lable = CanvasJS.formatNumber(lable);
        return lable;
      },
      interval: 1,
      includeZero: false
    },
    toolTip: {
      contentFormatter: function(e) {
        var content = "Data Values";
        for (var i = 0; i < e.entries.length; i++) {
          content += "</br>" + e.entries[i].dataPoint.x + " : ";
          content += CanvasJS.formatNumber(Math.round(Math.pow(10, e.entries[i].dataPoint.y)));
        }
        return content;
      }
    },
    data: [{
      type: "line",
      dataPoints: []
    }]
  }); convertToLog(chart.options.data); chart.render();

  function convertToLog(data) {
    var dataPoints;
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      dataPoints = data[j].dataPoints;
      for (var i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; i++) {
        dataPoints[i].y = Math.log10(dataPoints[i].y);
      }
    }
  }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Here I am trying to draw the graph using canvasjs. I am getting the input from the external API using an AJAX call. And storing the variables X and Y in the array. Providing that as an input to that canvasjs library for drawing the graph. But I am not able to draw the graph. The above snippet is the one I have done.

Comment: Your snippet has a syntax error.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have corrected that but still I am not able to draw the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chart wasn't getting rendered because the render method gets called before the data actually is loaded.

"x" & "y" should be in small instead of capital. The graph looks scrambled because the X Values in your JSON are not sorted.

Since the library now supports Logarithmic Scale on Y-Axis, you can use that instead of the work around.Here's a [documentation link](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisy/logarithmic/).

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //var dataPoints = [];
  // fetching the json data from api via AJAX call.
  var X = [];
  var Y = [];
  var data = [];

  function loadJSON(callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/cixax', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
        callback(xobj.responseText);
      }
    }
    xobj.send(null);
  }
  loadJSON(function(response) {
    var response;
    var field = JSON.parse(response);
    var values = [];
    //Iterating and storing leads & visits in a variable.
    var $this = field;
    for (var key in $this) {
      if ($this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var data = $this[key].dates;
        for (var val in data) {
          values.push({
            "x": data[val].visits, // Should be "x" & "y"
            "y": data[val].leads 
          });
        }
      }
    }
    //dataPoints = ({
    //  "values": values
    //});
    
    // Update the dataPoints & render the chart
    // x values need to be in sorted order
    chart.options.data[0].dataPoints = values;
    
    chart.render();
  });

  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    title: {
      text: "Log Scale on Axis Y - Workaround using Linear Axis"
    },
    axisY: {
      //valueFormatString: "0.## E0",
      title: "In log scale",
      labelFormatter: function(e) {
        var lable = Math.pow(10, e.value);
        if (lable >= 1000)
          lable = CanvasJS.formatNumber(lable / 1000) + "k";
        else
          lable = CanvasJS.formatNumber(lable);
        return lable;
      },
      interval: 1,
      includeZero: false
    },
    toolTip: {
      contentFormatter: function(e) {
        var content = "Data Values";
        for (var i = 0; i < e.entries.length; i++) {
          content += "</br>" + e.entries[i].dataPoint.x + " : ";
          content += CanvasJS.formatNumber(Math.round(Math.pow(10, e.entries[i].dataPoint.y)));
        }
        return content;
      }
    },
    data: [{
      type: "line",
      dataPoints: []
    }]
  }); //convertToLog(chart.options.data); chart.render();

  function convertToLog(data) { 
    var dataPoints;
    for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      dataPoints = data[j].dataPoints;
      for (var i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; i++) {
        dataPoints[i].y = Math.log10(dataPoints[i].y);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Is that possible to put log in x-axis?

Comment: @Raghavi Yes, take a look at the documentation page: https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisx/logarithmic/